# Print all local variables accessible to the current scope in Lua

Tags: lua, introspection

I know how to print "all" global variables using the following code

```
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    print("Global key", k, "value", v)
end
```

So my question is how to do that for all variables that are accessible from the currently executing function, something that can do what `locals()` does for Python.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an implementation of a `locals()` function. It will return a table of locals from the calling scope:

```
function locals()
  local variables = {}
  local idx = 1
  while true do
    local ln, lv = debug.getlocal(2, idx)
    if ln ~= nil then
      variables[ln] = lv
    else
      break
    end
    idx = 1 + idx
  end
  return variables
end
```

Notice that in the lua REPL, each line is a separate chunk with separate locals. Also, internal variables are returned (names start with '(' if you want to remove them):

```
> local a = 2; for x, v in pairs(locals()) do print(x, v) end
a   2
(*temporary)    function: 0x10359b38
```

---

Thanks for the accept. You have unlocked the last piece of the puzzle! ;-)

Upvalues are local variables from outer scopes, that are used in the current function. They are neither in `_G` nor in `locals()`

```
function upvalues()
  local variables = {}
  local idx = 1
  local func = debug.getinfo(2, "f").func
  while true do
    local ln, lv = debug.getupvalue(func, idx)
    if ln ~= nil then
      variables[ln] = lv
    else
      break
    end
    idx = 1 + idx
  end
  return variables
end
```

Example (notice you have to use a for it to show up):

```
> local a= 2; function f() local b = a; for x,v in pairs(upvalues()) do print(x,v) end end; f()
a   2
```

Comment: Why it stores `pairs` in `(*temporary)`?

Comment: happy, it's a Lua implementation thing

Comment: Same thing without the (*temporary):

function locals()
    local variables = {}
    local idx = 1
    while true do
        local ln, lv = debug.getlocal(2, idx)
        if ln == nil then
            return variables
        end
        variables[ln] = lv
        idx = 1 + idx
    end
  end

Answer (score 8):

Use `debug.getlocal`.

Comment: It's too short to be useful for someone hitting the web with the question I asked. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with Judge Maygarden's loop version above is simply `local i = 0`.
It does nothing because the first indexed with '0' will always return nil.

Remember Lua indexes by default start with '1', not '0' like C/C++.
You can use '0' for an index with your own types of course, but the default functions 
are expecting the default of '1' as the first index.

Just change it to `local i = 1` and his loop will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

See [`debug.getlocal`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getlocal):

```
local foobar = 1

local i = 0
repeat
    local k, v = debug.getlocal(1, i)
    if k then
        print(k, v)
        i = i + 1
    end
until nil == k
```

Output:

```
foobar  1
i       2
```

Comment: Did you run the code you pasted? I'm running it using Lua 5.1.4 on Ubuntu and it does not print anything at all. I saved the code on a file and executed in the console with `lua test.lua`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I ran it on Ubuntu 10.04 with the same version of Lua.

Comment: Did you place it in a file as is or wrap it in a function call?

Comment: I thought any chunk would do it, and a file is a chunk, isn't it? Anyway, I just wrapped it in a function to no avail either :(
I'm on Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty).

Comment: shouldn't the last statement be `k == nil` instead? or simpler `not k`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getfenv](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-getfenv) to get a local environment.

> **getfenv ([f])** Returns the current
>   environment in use by the function. f
>   can be a Lua function or a number that
>   specifies the function at that stack
>   level: Level 1 is the function calling
>   getfenv. If the given function is not
>   a Lua function, or if f is 0, getfenv
>   returns the global environment. The
>   default for f is 1.

**Edit:** sorry, I was wrong.

I just checked Lua source code. `debug.getlocal()` is the only way to get the local variables.
Lua uses an internal [Proto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) structure and doesn't give us access to that.
(Proto holds local properties plus a parent Proto reference. Iterating function's Proto, by using getfenv,
we also iterate inherited properties, not what we wanted)

Users can define their *Proto* s either with environments and the `set/getfenv` functions or by using metatables.

Comment: Your solution did not work. The following does not print `foobar`:

    local foobar = 1; for k,v in pairs(getfenv()) do print(k, v) end

Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe `getfenv` will only show globals withing the given scope/environment.

Comment: @Judge, yes, but we can replace function's env with some other. As I discovered, when we iterate over an env we also iterate over the inherited chain of internal prototypes. We cannot really get local declarations unless we use the built-in `debug.getlocal`.