# CMake: Print out all accessible variables in a script

Tags: cmake

I'm wondering if there is a way to print out all accessible variables in CMake. I'm not interested in the CMake variables - as in the `--help-variables` option. I'm talking about my variables that I defined, or the variables defined by included scripts.

I'm currently including:

```
INCLUDE (${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeBackwardCompatibilityCXX.cmake)
```

And I was hoping that I could just print out all the variables that are here, instead of having to go through all the files and read what was available - I may find some variables I didn't know about that may be useful. It would be good to aid learning & discovery. It is strictly for debugging/development.

This is similar to the question in *[Print all local variables accessible to the current scope in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834579/print-all-local-variables-accessible-to-the-current-scope-in-lua)*, but for CMake!

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 554, accepted):

Using the [`get_cmake_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_cmake_property.html) function, the following loop will print out all CMake variables defined and their values:

```
get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
list (SORT _variableNames)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

This can also be embedded in a convenience function which can optionally use a regular expression to print only a subset of variables with matching names

```
function(dump_cmake_variables)
    get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
    list (SORT _variableNames)
    foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        if (ARGV0)
            unset(MATCHED)
            string(REGEX MATCH ${ARGV0} MATCHED ${_variableName})
            if (NOT MATCHED)
                continue()
            endif()
        endif()
        message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Or, in a more compact form:

```
function(dump_cmake_variables)
    get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
    list (SORT _variableNames)
    foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        if ((NOT DEFINED ARGV0) OR _variableName MATCHES ${ARGV0})
            message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

To print environment variables, use CMake's [command mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode):

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-E" "environment")
```

Comment: That's a very useful snippet.  Why doesn't it print out **ENV** variables which I set on command line?

Comment: @Geremia you can copy this code block to file **myfile.txt** and run : **cmake -P myfile.txt**

Comment: `VARIABLES` lists only "variables defined in the current directory." https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html#prop_dir:VARIABLES

Comment: I had to remove the `STATUS` from the `message` command for the output to be visible.

Comment: Didn't work for me. all I got was variables starting with CMAKE_*

Comment: The last suggestion: "execute_process()" is not helpful when using CMAKE under eclipse on MAC for these reasons (1) Eclipse manages the command line to CMAKE, and (2) MACOS strips and resets ENV variables when you launch an "installed app" like eclipse that is installed for example in /Applications/Eclipse.app

Comment: Note that in newer versions of cmake, `VARIABLES` is a `DIRECTORY` property rather than a global property: so `get_cmake_property` should be replaced with `get_directory_property`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `NOT MATCHED` and `CONTINUE` instead of `MATCHED` and placing the message call into the if?

Comment: I think nowadays the matching can be simplified with something like `if (NOT (_variableName MATCHES ${ARGV0}) continue() endif()`

Answer (score 204):

Another way is to simply use:

```
cmake -LAH
```

From the [manpage](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options):

> `-L[A][H]`
>
> List non-advanced cached variables.
>
> List cache variables will run CMake and list all the variables from the CMake cache that are not marked as `INTERNAL` or `ADVANCED`. This will effectively display current CMake settings [...].
>
> If `A` is specified, then it will display also advanced variables.
>
> If `H` is specified, it will also display help for each variable.

Comment: Do this on your build directory

Comment: Note that this method does NOT print system variables (WIN32, UNIX, APPLE, etc.).

Comment: This does not print out all available libraries, only the cached ones.

Comment: This does not print out all variables, only the cached ones. (FTFY rafa)

Answer (score 10):

**`ccmake`** is a good interactive option to interactively inspect cached variables (`option(` or `set( CACHE`:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
ccmake ..
```

[image]

Comment: Useful tool :) However, the questions asks to print out all variables.. but this will only reveal cached variables.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to view all cmake's internal variables, is by executing cmake with the `--trace-expand` option.

This will give you a trace of all .cmake files executed and variables set on each line.

Answer (score 4):

based on @sakra

```
function(dump_cmake_variables)
    get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
    list (SORT _variableNames)
    foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        if (ARGV0)
            unset(MATCHED)

            #case sensitive match
            # string(REGEX MATCH ${ARGV0} MATCHED ${_variableName})
            #
            #case insenstitive match
            string( TOLOWER "${ARGV0}" ARGV0_lower )
            string( TOLOWER "${_variableName}" _variableName_lower )
            string(REGEX MATCH ${ARGV0_lower} MATCHED ${_variableName_lower})

            if (NOT MATCHED)
                continue()
            endif()
        endif()
        message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()

dump_cmake_variables("^Boost")
```

variable names are case sensitive

btw if you are interested in boost, it is `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` not `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS`, and it is `Boost_LIBRARIES` not `BOOST_LIBRARIES`, and by mistake I had BOOST_LIBRARIES instead of Boost_LIBRARIES, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html , better example for boost:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS RANDOM)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(myfile PRIVATE
 ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*message*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html) :

```
message([STATUS] "SUB_SOURCES : ${SUB_SOURCES}")
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the current answers allowed me to see the variables in my project subdirectory. Here's a solution:

```
function(print_directory_variables dir)
    # Dump variables:
    get_property(_variableNames DIRECTORY ${dir} PROPERTY VARIABLES)
    list (SORT _variableNames)
    foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        get_directory_property(_variableValue DIRECTORY ${dir} DEFINITION ${_variableName})
        message(STATUS "DIR ${dir}: ${_variableName}=${_variableValue}")
    endforeach()
endfunction(print_directory_variables)

# for example
print_directory_variables(.)
print_directory_variables(ui/qt)
```