# How to pass all variables to separate CMake instance?

Tags: variables, cmake, parameter-passing, execution

I would like to figure out how to efficiently pass all of the CMake variables to another execution step of CMake.
There is a way to [get all the variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script/9328525#9328525), but I'm hoping there is an efficient option other than looping over every variable and appending the strings together with `set()` as follows:

```
 get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
 foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    if(NOT ${_variablename} STREQUAL BASIS_PROPERTIES_ON_TESTS_RE)
      set(ALL_VARIABLES_COMMAND_LINE "${ALL_VARIABLES_COMMAND_LINE} -D ${_variableName}=\"${${_variableName}}\"\n")
    endif()
 endforeach()

 execute_process (
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" ${COMMON_ARGS}
            -D "PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS=${INCLUDE_DIRS}"
            -D "BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR=${BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR}"
            -D "EXTENSIONS=${EXTENSIONS}"
            ${ALL_VARIABLES_COMMAND_LINE}
            -D "CMAKE_FILE=${CMAKE_FILE}"
            -P "${BASIS_MODULE_PATH}/ConfigureIncludeFiles.cmake"
    RESULT_VARIABLE RT
  )
```

The problem with that method is that it will mess with escape characters and in some cases fail to execute the program.

Note: I currently write all the variables to disk and load them back in from there, but that operation takes 1/2 second. Since I need to run this script for over 100 independent packages the additional configuration time for that technique is too high.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of passing the whole list of variables as command-line parameters, I would form a new (temporary) CMake script (with `file(WRITE...)`) which sets all required variables and then execute that script with another instance of CMAke (`execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P /path/to/script...)`). Thus you'd avoid the necessity to fight against the bash escaping.

Certainly when writing the file you would need to escape variables values too, but in case of of CMake it's a much simpler task. It seems that the basic escaping should be as follows:

```
 set(VAR "A String with \" and \\ ")
 message(STATUS "VAR=[${VAR}]")

 string(REPLACE "\\" "\\\\" VAR_ ${VAR}) # escape \
 string(REPLACE "\"" "\\\"" VAR_ ${VAR_}) # escape "

 file(WRITE file.cmake "SET(VAR \"${VAR_}\")\n" )
 file(APPEND file.cmake "message(STATUS \"VAR=[\${VAR}]\")\n")
```

this cmake script creates another cmake script named `file.cmake` which prints the same variable as the first script.

Comment: We use this currently, and it adds 1/2 second to the configure time. Since I'm going to need to do this for over 100 independent packages I need a faster solution.

Comment: Well, couldn't you create the file once and then re-use it?

Comment: Each module exists as more or less independent subproject in its own subdirectory tree. Different dependencies and module attributes and build settings must therefore be considered. You thus need to write such file once for each module.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the `ConfigureIncludeFiles` module from the [CMake BASIS](http://opensource.andreasschuh.com/cmake-basis/) project. One way to improve configuration time for your project is to run `ConfigureIncludeFiles` as an include script.

Instead of running `ConfigureIncludeFiles` in a CMake subprocess started with `execute_process`, run the the module in the main CMake process as a CMake script with the [include](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainclude) command for each package that needs to be configured, i.e.:

```
# set up parameters for package 1
set (PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PACKAGE1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set (BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR ${PACKAGE1_BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
set (EXTENSIONS ${PACKAGE1_EXTENSIONS})
set (CMAKE_FILE ${PACKAGE1_CMAKE_FILE})
include(ConfigureIncludeFiles)
...
# set up parameters for package 2
set (PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PACKAGE2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set (BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR ${PACKAGE2_BINARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
set (EXTENSIONS ${PACKAGE2_EXTENSIONS})
set (CMAKE_FILE ${PACKAGE2_CMAKE_FILE})
include(ConfigureIncludeFiles)
```

Because the module runs in the main CMake process, it will implicitly have access to all CMake variables defined and there is no need to pass the variables explicitly.

Comment: That is right. The intention was, however, to defer the configuration to the build step such that the configure step does not need to be rerun every time a header file that was configured is edited. Initially CMake BASIS configured (or copied) all header files in order to organize them in the build tree in the same way they would be organized in the installation. As this comes with plenty of issues, such as compiler warnings/errors referring to the copy instead of the original which may lead to loss of changes, only files that really need to be configured are now. Typically just config.h.in.

Comment: That said, as now at most only one header file is typically configured, it is again reasonable to do this directly during the configure step without all the complicated logic required otherwise. That is the solution Andrew ended up implementing to improve the time needed for the configure step.