# Display CMake variables without running CMake on a CMakeLists.txt file or manually inspecting config.cmake?

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have a package called Foo. If I run CMake on a CMakeLists.txt file that contains `find_package(Foo)`, then I can print out the values of variables such as `${Foo_LIBRARIES}` and `${Foo_INCLUDES}`.

Is there an easy way to display these variables without having to run CMake on a CMakeLists.txt file, and without having to manually inspect the config.cmake file?

Answer (score 71):

You asked: (1) Is there an easy way to display these variables without having to run cmake on a CMakeLists.txt file, and (2) without having to manually inspect the config.cmake file?

I can give you a yes answer to (2) but it does require that you (re)run cmake. But since you can re-run your cmake configure step by simply executing `cmake .` in the build directory, re-running cmake should not keep you from trying this approach. My answer is given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328525/3154588) and uses the [get_cmake_property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/get_cmake_property.html) command. Here is that code encapsulated into a cmake macro, `print_all_variables`, so I can use it when debugging my cmake scripts.

```cmake
macro(print_all_variables)
    message(STATUS "print_all_variables------------------------------------------{")
    get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
    foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
    endforeach()
    message(STATUS "print_all_variables------------------------------------------}")
endmacro()
```

The macros are invoked with same syntax as cmake functions:

```
print_all_variables()
```

Answer (score 70):

To simply print a value, you could do something like this:

```
message(STATUS "foo include dir: ${foo_INCLUDE}")
```

where `${foo_INCLUDE}` is the value you desire to print.

Note: I'm using cmake > 3.14

Answer (score 7):

Run CMake and have a look at the cache with the `ccmake` GUI tool. Then you'll get all the variables.

Or run CMake with  `-LH` then you will get all variables printed after configuration.

So I think it is not possible to get the variables without running CMake.

Comment: this is great.  `-LH` without dot

Comment: This only prints cached variables

Answer (score 4):

Run `cmake` in find-package mode. Example to display a package`s include directories:

```
cmake -DNAME=ZLIB -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=COMPILE --find-package
```

Example to display the libraries:

```
cmake -DNAME=ZLIB -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=LINK --find-package
```

The `NAME` must be set to the package name. You can obtain your `COMPILER_ID` on [this page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html). `LANGUAGE` can be `C`, `CXX` or `Fortran`.

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't seem to work for me:`$ uname -a
Linux kaveri 4.18.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 8 00:06:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/assimp-4.1/
assimp-config.cmake  assimp-config-version.cmake
$ cmake -DNAME=assimp-4.1 -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=CXX -DMODE=LINK --find-package
assimp-4.1 not found.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.`

Comment: The package name is `assimp`, try with `-DNAME=assimp`

Comment: I still get the same response: assimp not found etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am always suspicious of variables changing values throughout a script somewhere so I like to see the value of a variable at a particular point in the running script.  Combining the ideas from both Phil and Aaron B. this is what I'm using:

```
function(PRINT_VAR VARNAME)
  message(STATUS "${VARNAME}: ${${VARNAME}}")
endfunction()
PRINT_VAR("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER")
```

Then I can just litter `PRINT_VAR` statements around like I'm debugging code back in 1980

Answer (score 1):

These variables are generally hardcoded into FindFoo.cmake so that it is not possible to extract them without running the function first. Note that sometimes the value of Foo_LIBRARIES depends on the system configuration, which is unknown until find_package(Foo) is run.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here for the extra visibility, but if you're using VS Code, the CMake Tools extension has commands to view/edit the variable cache, either using an intermediary UI or directly by opening the cache in a text editor tab so you don't have to go dig into your build folder for it.