# Change cmake source search location

Tags: cmake

I have the following directory structure:

```
├───3rd
│   └───lua // this is git submodule, I can't modify anything here
│       ├───doc
│       └───src
└───cmake
    └───lua // CMakeLists.txt for ../../3rd/lua is here
```

I'm pulling external library to my repo let's say lua. There's no cmake support in the distrubution. And I can't build it on windows with nmake. Then I want to create a `CMakeLists.txt` somewhere in my repo for lua.

Let's say I place `CMakeLists.txt` for lua in `./cmake/lua/CMakeLists.txt`. Relative to this location I have to specify sources prefixed with `../../3rd/lua/src/` which is not nice

```
set(SOURCES
    ../../3rd/lua/src/lapi.c
    ../../3rd/lua/src/lauxlib.c
    ../../3rd/lua/src/lbaselib.c
    <...>)
add_library(liblua ${SOURCES}).
```

Putting `../../3rd/lua/src/` into a variable and prefixing each of the source files with it is not nice too. So I want to change base search path for source files with `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rd/lua/src`. And I also want to affect base path for `include_directories`. I thought changing `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` to this will do, but it has no effect at all.

I used a script found here [CMAKE: Print out all accessible variables in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script) to list all variables and all of them referring to CMakeLists.txt location I changed to `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rd/lua/src`:

```
set(CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
set(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
set(CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
set(Project_SOURCE_DIR C:/dev/lua-external-cmake/3rd/lua/src)
```

It seems there is no such variable, since this change had no effect. I'm aware that changing some of those is utterly wrong. I did it just to find out if there will be any effect.

So, how do I change source search location and base path for include files in cmake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `source search path` in CMake. But you can easily "rebase" sources using common cmake commands:

```
set(SOURCES
    lapi.c
    lauxlib.c
    lbaselib.c
    <...>)
set(SOURCES_ABS)
foreach(source ${SOURCES})
    list(APPEND SOURCES_ABS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rd/lua/src/${source})
endforeach()
add_library(liblua ${SOURCES_ABS}).
```