# With 'find_package': how do I know which variables have to be used for linking?

Tags: cmake

I use `find_package()` to find some library. How do I know which variables it defines, so I could use them for linking with that library?

For example, the following `CMakeLists.txt` successfully is run by CMake, but then `make` fails at the linking stage, because `${DOCOPT_LIBRARIES}` was empty.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(test)

set(PROJECT_LIBS "")

find_package(docopt REQUIRED)
include_directories(${DOCOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(PROJECT_LIBS ${PROJECT_LIBS} ${DOCOPT_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_LIBS})
```

But I have no idea what else to try?

Comment: Define "fails upon linking".  What's the actual error?  What's the link command `cmake` is trying to use (`make VERBOSE=1` will print it)?

Comment: @StephenNewell Thanks for pointing out the shortcomings in my description. I have edited. The relevant output from `make VERBOSE=1` is `c++  -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of results of `find_package(XXX)` depends on the script which is actually used by this command:

1. `FindXXX.cmake`.

   This file is either shipped with the project which wants to use it, or with CMake. Usually, such "Find" scripts start with some description about their usage.
2. `XXXConfig.cmake` or `xxx-config.cmake`.

   "Config" scripts are usually installed with the package. Normally, they are generated by CMake using specific [CMake commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html). You need to consult the package's documentation for use such scripts properly.

If the package doesn't document the usage of its "Config" script, then you may only *guess* about its usage.

Reading a "Config" script itself could be difficult: CMake includes into it a lot of "sugar", which helps portability and compatibility.

Normally, a "Config" script provides some *IMPORTED* library target(s), which can be used with `target_link_libraries` call.

One may scan the project's `CMakeLists.txt` for a line like

```
install(TARGETS <targets...> EXPORT ...)
```

Here `<targets...>` denotes targets, which can be accessed after `find_package()` call.

Also scan for a line like

```
install(EXPORT ...)
```

if it has *NAMESPACE* option, then its value prepends all exported targets.

**Example**:

For docopt package, its [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L116) contains a line

```
install(TARGETS docopt EXPORT ${export_name} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

thus its `docopt` target is exported.

As installation of the export file

```
install(EXPORT ${export_name} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/docopt")
```

doesn't contain NAMESPACE option, the export target is accessible with its original name:

```
find_package(docopt REQUIRED)
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
# Use *IMPORTED* 'docopt' target
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} docopt)
```

Answer (score 2):

After performing a `find_package`, perhaps you can't make cmake print exactly the variables that the package specifically defined, but perhaps you may appreciate the following code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328525/4935114), which gives lists all of the variables defined at a certain point in your cmake files. Here's and example usage:

```
find_package(FluidSynth REQUIRED)
get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
list (SORT _variableNames)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

Which prints many variables including those set by `fluidsynth` - search for variables beginning with `fluidsynth` and their values.

Comment: This method reports *all* known variables as well as macros. How can the report of "all variables" be reduced to strictly only those variables provided by the FluidSynth package?

Comment: Directly, there is no way to detect what variables are defined by the arbitrary cmake files of a package, but it might be possible to write cmake code that would calculate the difference between the variables that were defined before and after the `find_package`. Usually, just for debugging, it should be good enough to use the code above to print all variables, and lookup there for variables with names that include the package's name (with possibly different casing).