# After CMake install, I can't find a package with `find_package`

Tags: c++, build, cmake, libraries

I have installed a library (SDL) with the following command:

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

I read in the documentation that installed packages are going to be registered in the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`.

But when I print out the variable it is empty.

Currently I am using Windows, and I read online that I should register the installation path in the registry, but it did not help at all.

How can I find, for example, SDL with find_package()?

Comment: ***Currently I am using windows*** Sometimes this means you have to tell it where to look. I use batch files and environment variables that feed CMake variables to force it to pick the version that I want. Although this is partly due to me using more than 1 version of Visual Studio combined with building for 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Check out CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2799037

Comment: I checked out that, but it is not working as I want to.

I added `SDL2                           2.0.8 : T:\installed\2.0.8\CMake` TO the package registry but when I want to include the SDL2 package, it says that there is no FINDSDL2.cmake, altough in this tutorial https://github.com/Wigner-GPU-Lab/Teaching/tree/master/CMake/Lesson3_Dependecies the writer did not have a find script neither.

Comment: I just had this exact same problem when installing and trying to use Google Benchmark on Windows - to work around it I used CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, so the command I used was `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Program Files" -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..` I thought it should work without but apparently not. I'm going to keep digging as CMake did install Benchmark to the right location, so it must be the default somewhere! :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Using the get_cmake_property function the following loop will print
>   out all CMake variables defined and their values:
>
> ```
> get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
> list (SORT _variableNames)
> foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
>     message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
> endforeach()
> ```
>
> To print environment variables use CMake's command mode:
>
> ```
> execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-E" "environment")
> ```

It prints:

```
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local;/usr;/;/usr;/usr/local;/usr/X11R6;/usr/pkg;/opt
```

(Credits to [Sakra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328525/466339))

You can search your source tree for a file named `FindSDL*.cmake` then try to find this file in your `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` directories.

If `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` is still empty, try to locate `FindSDL*.cmake` in your entire computer to check whether files are being installed somewhere `cmake` knows or try to append this path to your `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`.

You can also check this link: *[Using SDL2 with CMake](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this wasn't working for you is because your `find_package` command came before your `project` command in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. If you ensure `project` is the first command (after `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION <NUM>`) then all of the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_***` variables will be initialized correctly :)

I actually stumbled across this post after having the exact same problem (see my comment on the initial question). I tried the advice posted by j4x using the `foreach VARIABLES` command to print all the variables and serendipitously pasted it after my `project` command. I noticed `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` was a sensible value - I then moved the code above the `project` command and noticed far fewer variables were printed :P `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` was no where to be seen...

I hope this works for you too!