# CMAKE: "-rdynamic" problem using ld (set CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE) as the linker

Tags: cmake

I am trying to use `ld` as the linker for CMake, and thus I have the following tow lines:

```
set(CMAKE_LINKER "/usr/bin/ld")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE  "<CMAKE_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

However, when the program links, it provide a `-rdynamic` option for the linker. That option is suitable for `gcc`, but not for `ld`.

Anyone know where this option come from?   So that I can add a line to change that variable (I assume it is a variable storing this option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered the question, and I already found it, I post it here.

By the help of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script), I print out all the variables and found it to be 
`CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS`