# Bazel: list available parameters

Tags: bazel

In cmake, whenever you want to list all the available parameters, you can pass "cmake -LAH". That would [output every parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script) for the current project. I am looking for the bazel equivalent of it.

In bazel, as far as I know, the workflow is a bit different, since it works with environment parameters, such as:

```
export PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python
export USE_DEFAULT_PYTHON_LIB_PATH=1
```

What is the bazel equivalent, to "cmake -LAH", to list all these parameters available for a project?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CMake. Could you explain what you mean by parameters (is it environment variables? is it tools the build uses? is it dependencies of the target you're building?), or what are you trying to understand by observing these parameters?

Comment: What I mean by that: sometimes, creators of cmakefiles add some options, to link to a specific library for instance, or to add a feature. Thus, they create a flag that can be seen by cmake -LAH. These options are sometimes use to specify the location of the library (and some of the flags comes with the cmake tool, so are always there, no matter the project, for instance to define the compilation optimizations). I am looking for the bazel equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see the build dependency graph then [check](https://bazel.build/tutorials/cpp#review_the_dependency_graph) . You can  list all of them using the  **bazel query** command. You can also list them by  going through [visualisation](https://blog.bazel.build/2015/06/17/visualize-your-build.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31906652)