# How to get "sizeof" a table in Lua?

Tags: memory, lua, love2d

I'm dabbling in Love2D using Lua and have just implemented a StateMachine to handle transitions between a set of states e.g. IntroState, MenuState, PlayState etc..

In previous programs I usally release objects and/or states that are only a "one-time-deal", iow will only be presented to the player once during the lifetime of the application. In C++ I use the [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator which returns the size in bytes of the passed object, just to get some feedback of how much memory I release at a certain point.

Are there any **corresponding** keyword or trick in Lua to achieve this?

Comment: There's [getsize](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize), an external module that can do that. It's for PUC-Rio Lua only (no LuaJIT), because it accesses internal data structures. However, Lua will hold on to the memory of the objects until they are unreachable *and* the garbage collector reclaims them, and that could be much later, so such feedback doesn't make much sense in Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need fine-grained information, you can use [getsize](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize) as @siffiejoe mentioned in combination with some table traversal to get to all local and global objects. If you need more coarse-grained approach, you can use `collectgarbage('count')` to get the total memory used by Lua.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734931/1442917) and [this lua discussion on memory tracking](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-09/msg00122.html) may be of some help. Note that you don't have control over memory release as it's handled by the garbage collector (although there are several GC settings you can tweak).