# Find out what is taking my memory in torch7

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, lua, caffe, torch

I have written a rather complex torch application and it works quite well, that is if it doesn't run out of memory. Now I have tried to see what sort of inputs or situations cause it too seemingly randomly run out of memory but so far I have had little to no success. So now I'm looking for a way to check which variables take how much (v)ram.

I can with a simple statement switch between running my code on caffe:cuda or caffe:cl which changes whatever or not my program runs in RAM or on the GPU, I imagine that such a switch will make validating my memory usage a lot easier.

I have already tried to use `print(collectgarbage("count")*1024)` to check how much memory is in usage at a given point in time however this does not clearly show me where the memory is being used, perhaps because the program is relatively complex (although there are a few variables which I suspect are hugging a lot of memory, neural networks, large matrices and such).

I already know that once I have identified who is hogging my memory I can assign a nill value to it and call the garbage collector too free it.

So in short is there a program or a tool that allows me to run a torch program and then list each variable and it's memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried google :) 
But here you are:

- [**Torch7-profiling**](https://github.com/e-lab/Torch7-profiling)
- [**Neural Model profiler script**](https://github.com/e-lab/Torch7-profiling/blob/master/profile-model.lua)
- ["How to Profile a Lua Script using Pepperfish"](http://help.interfaceware.com/v6/how-to-profile-your-lua-script)
- [Easy Lua Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725744/easy-lua-profiling)

tbo, I've never had memory issues with **Torch7** so it might be your implementation which is just not optimal. It might be a loop without `collectgarbage` call somewhere where it should be, e.g. in a training loop or between the epochs.

Comment: The first two links appear to focus on profiling an existing network and not it's memory usage, is that correct? The third link allows me to check how often a function was called and how much time it spend there, again not memory and the fourth one only deals with memory by using the collectgarbage("count") statement. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct. If you are looking for sophisticated profiling tools in the world of Lua, you are out of luck.