# How can I perf a programe written in lua embedding with C?

Tags: c, lua, profiling

I have a program written in C and Lua.
Now, I want to perf this program, print the hot call stack for example.

I don't have any tool or any idea to do this.

```lua
function fa()
   dosomething()
end

function fb() 
   fa()
end
```

```
int main() {
    lua_call("fb")
}
```

When profiling this program, I hope to print the calling stack like this:
0: fa
1: fb
2: main

Comment: See http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProfilingLuaCode, https://github.com/charlesmallah/lua-profiler, http://luaprofiler.luaforge.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725744/easy-lua-profiling

Comment: You must not understand what I mean. The program is written in C, and it calls Lua function. Now I need to profile this program to print the calling stack from C function to Lua function. As showed in the example, "main" is C code, while "fa" and "fb" are Lua code.

Comment: If you want to print a stacktrace (instead of profiling), just insert the line `print(debug.traceback())` inside your `fa` body

Comment: debug.traceback() can print C's stack?  Actually I need to print the call cost, something like calling frequency or time cost of each function from C to Lua or again from Lua to C ...