# Transferring Python globals and locals to Lua

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua, eval, lupa

I'm trying to write Pyton 3 wrapper for `eval()` function for Lua source strings.

For executing Lua expressions in Python I use `eval()` from [Lupa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa) library. But signature of `eval()` in Lupa is differ from Python built-in `eval()`:

- Lupa eval: `eval(source: str)`,
- Python eval: `eval(source: str, globals: dict, locals: dict)`.

Of course, if `globals` and `locals` are `None`, I can simply write my function. Calling Lupa's eval within self-wrintten eval is enough for this:

```
import lupa

lua_run = lupa.LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)

def eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None):
    return lua_run.eval(expression)
```

But what I have to do if I want to transfer non-empty `globals` and `locals` dictionaries?

Maybe, it isn't possible in Lupa and I have to use some other libraries?

Comment: You can access the tables from inside Lua, allowing you to setfenv/_ENV for globals.

Comment: And the debug library can be used to get a list of locals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834579/print-all-local-variables-accessible-to-the-current-scope-in-lua